# What are the drawbacks to a Vcc (positive voltage) plane?

Tags: layout, pcb-design

I'm familiar with using ground planes when designing circuit boards.  I've started used power planes for the predominant voltage in a couple of my designs, and I'm wondering if that's a bad idea.  I'm only working with 2-layer boards, and I've found that putting a ground plane on one layer and a power plane on the other layer makes placing components much simpler.  I've been building low-density boards with only low-frequency digital signals, and very few (if any) analog signals.

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: As far as (AC) signal is concerned, as well-decoupled Vcc plane acts the same as a ground plane. So stick in a big cap and pour your Vcc plane if it suits your design better.

Answer (score 4):

With proper decoupling Vcc is as good as ground as far as EMI is concerned. So an extra plane is a good thing. However, if you're working on only two layers the plane may be cut into several islands. Try to keep connections as short as possible.

Answer (score 3):

- Supply nets:

**Pro:** For supplying nets on your PCB (as opposed to signals that are routed with respect to GND), a supply plane is just as important as a ground (return) plane. Remember that currents always flow in loops, and in the case of copper planes, the loops include both the supply plane and the ground plane. In this case, think of the two planes for VCC and GND as a capacitor that stabilizes your supply rails for all the ICs and everything else.

**Con:** Polygons (planes) for VCC and GND need a lot of space and may not be necessary when you're just doing low speed stuff.

- Signal nets:

The reason for planes with signal nets is that they act as a shield, or they form a strip line with the signal lines, creating a defined impedance. In these cases, you don't use planes that also carry supplying current for other parts of your board because these currents will influence your precious and sensitive analog signals; instead, you connect the planes in a way that returns nothing but the return current of any field the planes "catch". A "star grounding" technique might be one option to accomplish this. Theoretically, a plane connected to VCC will act just as well as a plane connected to GND, it just needs a good (low impedance) path to *any* stable voltage. In practice, it will often be much easier to use GND for this purpose.